# FBA and audience targeting in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, fba, targeting, audience

I want to use audience targeting feature for webpart with FBA. I tried to add FBA user directly in sharepoint group or added the user to a asp.net role and then added the role to sharepoint group, but both failed. My observation is that all FBA users can see the webpart content no matter whether they are specified in audience targeting or not.

After googling it, I found there are three different conclusion about this,

1. FBA cannot be used with audience targeting
2. FBA can be used with audience targeting
3. FBA can be used with audience targeting if the FBA user is added directly to sharepoint group

May I know which is the correct explanation? Where can I find official Microsoft documentation regarding to this problem?